How can I get helm-exwm to include the workspace/frame in the listing?
When I use the helm-exwm to list the EXWM buffers, the workspaces containing the buffers are not included in the listing.
In fact I notice that C-x b and C-x B don't include the frames which hold the buffers, or the most recent frames that contained the  buffers if they are off screen, so this maybe a wider case of the usual practice in Emacs where frame listings are not included in Emacs.
I use the command (exwm-workspace-switch-to-buffer(helm-exwm)) to switch to the relevant frames if the exwm buffers are not in the current frame.
For instance I usually run web browsing instances in different workspaces and it is frustrating when choose the browser running in the wrong frame.
Is there a way to add the workspace containing the buffers to the listing?

good question, any luck?

@xpusostomos It is something I planned to work on. I haven't started it yet, but I have sketched most of it out.

sure would be nice if plain exwm also could show the workspace.
